# pycrypto installation with error "GMP or MPIR library not found" in windows 8.1

Tags: python, compiler-errors, windows-8.1, pycrypto

How can i get pycrypto installation to recognize GMP library in windows 8.1?
I am using Windows 7 SDK (7.0) to compile. Python version is 2.7.8

This is the full error:

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
Successfully installed pycrypto-2.6.1
```

pip freeze:

```
ecdsa==0.13
gmpy2==2.0.5
pycrypto==2.6.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

are there any logs i can post that can help someone point me in the right direction.